# show elements on form submit that are hidden on first load

Tags: select, html, hide, show

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
              {
              $("#kids").change(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == "1")
    {
        $("#age1").show();
        $("#age2").hide();
    }   
        else if($(this).val() == "2")
    {
        $("#age1").show();
        $("#age2").show();
    }

        else
    {
        $("#age1").hide();
        $("#age2").hide();

    }
        });
         $("#age1").hide();
         $("#age2").hide();
        });
```

The code opens on select-change depending on the chosen value either (1 or 2) one input field or both of them. Input fields are hidden on the opening of the page. Once I have chosen one of the values in a select field  I am having an input field(s) shown and after submiting the form  I am validating the form. I am saving the select field chosen value in a session variable and having it displayed on the reload of the page.

How can I get the input field(s) (that are normally hidden on the first page load) now shown depending on the session (select) variable saved.

Comment: please show your HTML codes as well

Comment: What is handling the session variables? Php?

Comment: html code is very long, for example age1 is a <li id="age1"> that is shown or hidden depending on what is chosen in a select field. it is very simple, i just wonder if it is possible to have it shown on reload

Comment: php is handling variables